# more pythonic/efficient loop nesting

Tags: python, for-loop, nested-loops

I am coming from a java background and am new to python

is there a more efficient or more pythonic what of writing:

```
S_BOX_TABLE = [
    [BitArray('0x63'), BitArray('0x7C'), BitArray('0x77'), BitArray('0x7B'), BitArray('0xF2'), BitArray('0x6B'), BitArray('0x6F'), BitArray('0xC5'), BitArray('0x30'), BitArray('0x01'), BitArray('0x67'), BitArray('0x2B'), BitArray('0xFE'), BitArray('0xD7'), BitArray('0xAB'), BitArray('0x76')],
    [BitArray('0xCA'), BitArray('0x82'), BitArray('0xC9'), BitArray('0x7D'), BitArray('0xFA'), BitArray('0x59'), BitArray('0x47'), BitArray('0xF0'), BitArray('0xAD'), BitArray('0xD4'), BitArray('0xA2'), BitArray('0xAF'), BitArray('0x9C'), BitArray('0xA4'), BitArray('0x72'), BitArray('0xC0')],
    [BitArray('0xB7'), BitArray('0xFD'), BitArray('0x93'), BitArray('0x26'), BitArray('0x36'), BitArray('0x3F'), BitArray('0xF7'), BitArray('0xCC'), BitArray('0x34'), BitArray('0xA5'), BitArray('0xE5'), BitArray('0xF1'), BitArray('0x71'), BitArray('0xD8'), BitArray('0x31'), BitArray('0x15')],
    [BitArray('0x04'), BitArray('0xC7'), BitArray('0x23'), BitArray('0xC3'), BitArray('0x18'), BitArray('0x96'), BitArray('0x05'), BitArray('0x9A'), BitArray('0x07'), BitArray('0x12'), BitArray('0x80'), BitArray('0xE2'), BitArray('0xEB'), BitArray('0x27'), BitArray('0xB2'), BitArray('0x75')],
    [BitArray('0x09'), BitArray('0x83'), BitArray('0x2C'), BitArray('0x1A'), BitArray('0x1B'), BitArray('0x6E'), BitArray('0x5A'), BitArray('0xA0'), BitArray('0x52'), BitArray('0x3B'), BitArray('0xD6'), BitArray('0xB3'), BitArray('0x29'), BitArray('0xE3'), BitArray('0x2F'), BitArray('0x84')],
    [BitArray('0x53'), BitArray('0xD1'), BitArray('0x00'), BitArray('0xED'), BitArray('0x20'), BitArray('0xFC'), BitArray('0xB1'), BitArray('0x5B'), BitArray('0x6A'), BitArray('0xCB'), BitArray('0xBE'), BitArray('0x39'), BitArray('0x4A'), BitArray('0x4C'), BitArray('0x58'), BitArray('0xCF')],
    [BitArray('0xD0'), BitArray('0xEF'), BitArray('0xAA'), BitArray('0xFB'), BitArray('0x43'), BitArray('0x4D'), BitArray('0x33'), BitArray('0x85'), BitArray('0x45'), BitArray('0xF9'), BitArray('0x02'), BitArray('0x7F'), BitArray('0x50'), BitArray('0x3C'), BitArray('0x9F'), BitArray('0xA8')],
    [BitArray('0x51'), BitArray('0xA3'), BitArray('0x40'), BitArray('0x8F'), BitArray('0x92'), BitArray('0x9D'), BitArray('0x38'), BitArray('0xF5'), BitArray('0xBC'), BitArray('0xB6'), BitArray('0xDA'), BitArray('0x21'), BitArray('0x10'), BitArray('0xFF'), BitArray('0xF3'), BitArray('0xD2')],
    [BitArray('0xCD'), BitArray('0x0C'), BitArray('0x13'), BitArray('0xEC'), BitArray('0x5F'), BitArray('0x97'), BitArray('0x44'), BitArray('0x17'), BitArray('0xC4'), BitArray('0xA7'), BitArray('0x7E'), BitArray('0x3D'), BitArray('0x64'), BitArray('0x5D'), BitArray('0x19'), BitArray('0x73')],
    [BitArray('0x60'), BitArray('0x81'), BitArray('0x4F'), BitArray('0xDC'), BitArray('0x22'), BitArray('0x2A'), BitArray('0x90'), BitArray('0x88'), BitArray('0x46'), BitArray('0xEE'), BitArray('0xB8'), BitArray('0x14'), BitArray('0xDE'), BitArray('0x5E'), BitArray('0x0B'), BitArray('0xDB')],
    [BitArray('0xE0'), BitArray('0x32'), BitArray('0x3A'), BitArray('0x0A'), BitArray('0x49'), BitArray('0x06'), BitArray('0x24'), BitArray('0x5C'), BitArray('0xC2'), BitArray('0xD3'), BitArray('0xAC'), BitArray('0x62'), BitArray('0x91'), BitArray('0x95'), BitArray('0xE4'), BitArray('0x79')],
    [BitArray('0xE7'), BitArray('0xC8'), BitArray('0x37'), BitArray('0x6D'), BitArray('0x8D'), BitArray('0xD5'), BitArray('0x4E'), BitArray('0xA9'), BitArray('0x6C'), BitArray('0x56'), BitArray('0xF4'), BitArray('0xEA'), BitArray('0x65'), BitArray('0x7A'), BitArray('0xAE'), BitArray('0x08')],
    [BitArray('0xBA'), BitArray('0x78'), BitArray('0x25'), BitArray('0x2E'), BitArray('0x1C'), BitArray('0xA6'), BitArray('0xB4'), BitArray('0xC6'), BitArray('0xE8'), BitArray('0xDD'), BitArray('0x74'), BitArray('0x1F'), BitArray('0x4B'), BitArray('0xBD'), BitArray('0x8B'), BitArray('0x8A')],
    [BitArray('0x70'), BitArray('0x3E'), BitArray('0xB5'), BitArray('0x66'), BitArray('0x48'), BitArray('0x03'), BitArray('0xF6'), BitArray('0x0E'), BitArray('0x61'), BitArray('0x35'), BitArray('0x57'), BitArray('0xB9'), BitArray('0x86'), BitArray('0xC1'), BitArray('0x1D'), BitArray('0x9E')],
    [BitArray('0xE1'), BitArray('0xF8'), BitArray('0x98'), BitArray('0x11'), BitArray('0x69'), BitArray('0xD9'), BitArray('0x8E'), BitArray('0x94'), BitArray('0x9B'), BitArray('0x1E'), BitArray('0x87'), BitArray('0xE9'), BitArray('0xCE'), BitArray('0x55'), BitArray('0x28'), BitArray('0xDF')],
    [BitArray('0x8C'), BitArray('0xA1'), BitArray('0x89'), BitArray('0x0D'), BitArray('0xBF'), BitArray('0xE6'), BitArray('0x42'), BitArray('0x68'), BitArray('0x41'), BitArray('0x99'), BitArray('0x2D'), BitArray('0x0F'), BitArray('0xB0'), BitArray('0x54'), BitArray('0xBB'), BitArray('0x16')]]

for k in range(len(state_matrix)):
    for l in range(len(state_matrix[k])):
        state_matrix[k][l] = self.__sBoxSubstitution(state_matrix[k][l])

def __sBoxSubstitution(self, byte):
    column, row = byte.cut(4)
    return self.S_BOX_TABLE[row.int][column.int]
```

Comment: Don't always aim to reduce amount of lines. Specially when it reduce readability. Nothing wrong with nested loops in Python...

Comment: i know. i have just added the __sBoxSubstitution method into the question

Comment: it is taking up quite a lot of time when i am recursively passing lots of data trhough my program

Comment: What does `byte.cut`? May you can tell us a bit more about the operations you have to do itself. Seems to be an S-Box from AES? Why you try to implement your own AES? http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/18197/why-shouldnt-we-roll-our-own

Comment: I think a pythonic way would be to use just an integer array and may matrices from numpy?

Comment: Don't rely on a "more efficient" solution would improve that drastically. If you do it this way you'll (probably) still have to do two nested loops in one way or another and do some work in each iteration. And as for "pythonic" it's just another name for "readable code", which is not a very strict attribute - nested loops are fine whenever they're needed. What you might want to consider is whether you need to do the work this way, maybe you could rework your solution if you look at the bigger picture?

Comment: @wenzul the cut() method is simply a way to split a string of bits into small equal chunks. the point of implementing my own AES is simply to gain a fuller understanding of the implementation of the algorithm as applied in software. it is not intended for encryption at a high level at all and I am not planning on 'releasing' it

Comment: Ok, so can you tell us a bit more about `state_matrix` and why you end up with strings in it?

Comment: I am using the bitstring module from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bitstring/3.1.3   as i'm familiar with the BitArray class it offers. objects are created by BitArray('0b10101010') or BitArray('0xAA')     state matrix is simply the 16 byte state arranged in a 4x4 matrix for easier shift rows in the AES algorithm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Few things -

1. You can iterate over a list directly, you do not need to take its length and then iterate over the indices and take element using indices.
2. Seems like for every item in the 2D list, you are running a function and storing the result of the function back , you can use list comprehension for this (They may be a little faster than their for-loop counterparts , though this would create a new matrix and assign that new matrix to state_matrix inplace)

Code -

```
state_matrix[:] = [[self.__sBoxSubstitution(y) for y in x] for x in state_matrix ]
```

Assigning to `state_matrix` inplace, as that would be the exact behavior of the original nested loop.

Comment: Note that for the first point it will require that the elements are mutable, otherwise you will need the indices anyway (in order to replace the elements). The second point however is quite elegant solution.

Comment: True , good point. But I think `enumerate()` would be a cleaner approach in that case.

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth - another nested loop based version, which I feel is however much more readable than the original version:

```
for k, row in enumerate(state_matrix):
    for l, element in enumerate(row):
        state_matrix[k][l] = self.__sBoxSubstitution(element)
```

It has the advantage of not creating a completely new matrix - which might be a nice feature if your matrix becomes really large in terms of memory.

Comment: You cannot subscribe a list by using `state_matrix[k, l]`, you still need `state_matrix[k][l]`.

Answer (score 0):

If you look for more performance in python, you should prefer the functions `map`, `filter` and `reduce`. The loops of these are significant faster than pure python loops. I have not compared it regarding runtime, but it should be a little faster.

In your case you end up with something like:

```
state_matrix = map(lambda (k, row): 
                   map(lambda l: self.__sBoxSubstitution(state_matrix[k][l]),
                       range(len(row))
                      ),
                   enumerate(state_matrix)
                   )
```

---

**Sidenote**

I tried to simplify the code a bit, but it's just a sidenote to your question...

Also you can use `numpy` for array/matrix access and operations which are faster than python lists. The instantiation needs more time, but I think accessing it could be faster. A Python list is an array of pointers to Python objects. A NumPy array is an array of uniform values.

```
import numpy as np

S_BOX_TABLE = np.array([
    [0x63, 0x7C, 0x77, 0x7B, 0xF2, 0x6B, 0x6F, 0xC5, 0x30, 0x01, 0x67, 0x2B, 0xFE, 0xD7, 0xAB, 0x76],
    [0xCA, 0x82, 0xC9, 0x7D, 0xFA, 0x59, 0x47, 0xF0, 0xAD, 0xD4, 0xA2, 0xAF, 0x9C, 0xA4, 0x72, 0xC0],
    [0xB7, 0xFD, 0x93, 0x26, 0x36, 0x3F, 0xF7, 0xCC, 0x34, 0xA5, 0xE5, 0xF1, 0x71, 0xD8, 0x31, 0x15],
    [0x04, 0xC7, 0x23, 0xC3, 0x18, 0x96, 0x05, 0x9A, 0x07, 0x12, 0x80, 0xE2, 0xEB, 0x27, 0xB2, 0x75],
    [0x09, 0x83, 0x2C, 0x1A, 0x1B, 0x6E, 0x5A, 0xA0, 0x52, 0x3B, 0xD6, 0xB3, 0x29, 0xE3, 0x2F, 0x84],
    [0x53, 0xD1, 0x00, 0xED, 0x20, 0xFC, 0xB1, 0x5B, 0x6A, 0xCB, 0xBE, 0x39, 0x4A, 0x4C, 0x58, 0xCF],
    [0xD0, 0xEF, 0xAA, 0xFB, 0x43, 0x4D, 0x33, 0x85, 0x45, 0xF9, 0x02, 0x7F, 0x50, 0x3C, 0x9F, 0xA8],
    [0x51, 0xA3, 0x40, 0x8F, 0x92, 0x9D, 0x38, 0xF5, 0xBC, 0xB6, 0xDA, 0x21, 0x10, 0xFF, 0xF3, 0xD2],
    [0xCD, 0x0C, 0x13, 0xEC, 0x5F, 0x97, 0x44, 0x17, 0xC4, 0xA7, 0x7E, 0x3D, 0x64, 0x5D, 0x19, 0x73],
    [0x60, 0x81, 0x4F, 0xDC, 0x22, 0x2A, 0x90, 0x88, 0x46, 0xEE, 0xB8, 0x14, 0xDE, 0x5E, 0x0B, 0xDB],
    [0xE0, 0x32, 0x3A, 0x0A, 0x49, 0x06, 0x24, 0x5C, 0xC2, 0xD3, 0xAC, 0x62, 0x91, 0x95, 0xE4, 0x79],
    [0xE7, 0xC8, 0x37, 0x6D, 0x8D, 0xD5, 0x4E, 0xA9, 0x6C, 0x56, 0xF4, 0xEA, 0x65, 0x7A, 0xAE, 0x08],
    [0xBA, 0x78, 0x25, 0x2E, 0x1C, 0xA6, 0xB4, 0xC6, 0xE8, 0xDD, 0x74, 0x1F, 0x4B, 0xBD, 0x8B, 0x8A],
    [0x70, 0x3E, 0xB5, 0x66, 0x48, 0x03, 0xF6, 0x0E, 0x61, 0x35, 0x57, 0xB9, 0x86, 0xC1, 0x1D, 0x9E],
    [0xE1, 0xF8, 0x98, 0x11, 0x69, 0xD9, 0x8E, 0x94, 0x9B, 0x1E, 0x87, 0xE9, 0xCE, 0x55, 0x28, 0xDF],
    [0x8C, 0xA1, 0x89, 0x0D, 0xBF, 0xE6, 0x42, 0x68, 0x41, 0x99, 0x2D, 0x0F, 0xB0, 0x54, 0xBB, 0x16]])

def sBoxSubstitution(state_matrix):
    return map(lambda row:
               map(lambda element:
                   S_BOX_TABLE[element & 0x0F][(element & 0xF0) >> 4],
                   row
               ),
               state_matrix
           )
```